# Comparison between time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, anova

I have a methodological question that my relatively basic knowledge of statistics cannot solve. 
I want to compare two sets of observations made in two independent groups (with 15 subjects in such group) over time, organized as follows: the two groups are cell cultures and the measured variable is the proliferation rate (continuous variable). Every time the culture plate is "filled", cells are resuspended and replated (the amount of cells at replating is the same for every subject in every group), and this is called a "passage". At passage 3, 6, 9 and 12 we measured the proliferation rate at 4 time points (12, 34, 48, 72 hrs, with 3 simultaneous determinations per subject).

I'd like to find a way to compare the two groups in terms of proliferation rate at the different passages, given the time dependency of the observations within the single passage and the putative time dependency between passages. Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: A "passage" is the interval between Cell plating for colture and cells filling the plate (due to proliferation), with the need to resuspend and replate them. In the course of specific passages we collect some measurements of PR at specific time points. So we have, for every subject (and three times per time point): p3_12hrs, p3_24hrs, p3_48hrs, p6_12hrs, p6_24hrs, p6_48hrs and so on and so on. The two groups are a clinical group and a healthy control group.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by passage and how it is different from the time points at which you take measurements? What is the difference between the two groups?

Comment: A "passage" is defined as the interval between Cell plating for colture and cells filling the plate (due to proliferation), with the need to resuspend and replate them. During a passage, whose length vary on the basis of proliferation Speed, we collect some measurements of PR at specific time points (three measurements per time point). So we have, for every subject and three times per time point: p3_12hrs, p3_24hrs, p3_48hrs, p6_12hrs, p6_24hrs, p6_48hrs and so on and so on. The two groups are a clinical group and a healthy control group.

Comment: Someone suggested me the use of ARIMA models, but I really don't know how to implement them for the analysis. Could someone help me?